# Old TV series, children (?) traveling through a maze with a computerized map

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the name of a series that was probably from the 70's or 80's that involved a small group (made up of children?) who were travelling through a maze or network of tunnels with the help of a computerized map (which sort of reminded me of the Hitchhiker's Guide in a way).

- I think they were travelling in something like a mine cart or amusement part ride.
- I also recall there being someone — a young man — who was somehow advising them from afar

  - but he was trapped under a waterfall and was covered in green clumps of something from the falls.
  - He was eventually freed.
- And there was an enemy they were trying to outwit.

Comment: This reminds me of certain bits of Knightmare; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jls0kCeadQs

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/80s-kids-sci-show-set-in-ny-brownstone-where-inventor-has-invented-teleporting (which is newer)

Answer (score 6):

Do you remember if it was a live-action kid's educational show?

It's a bit of a reach, but it makes me think of '[Read All About It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_All_About_It!)', which was an educational show (out of Canada) from 1979 to 1983.  There were three children who were usually the protagonists, and the description for chapter 18 is:

> Chapter 18: THE PLANET OF MAZE - Lynne and Sam help Chris and his uncle escape from the Planet of Maze by answering riddling questions.

They **are** riding around in what looks like an amusement cart ride.

It's VERY low resolution, but the episode in question can currently be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzaTmQDC0-M).

Comment: Wow. I've had this same question in my head for ages, but I could never quite figure out how to phrase it.