# 80s kid's sci show set in NY brownstone where inventor has invented teleporting machine

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the '80s, as a child in school, I saw the first few episodes of a U.S. kids' TV series, set in a New-York-style brownstone building. A group of kids break into the building, which used to be where a strange scientist worked, possibly a relative of one of the kids. They find a machine invented by the scientist and accidentally turn it on. It transports a few kids into another place, where the scientist is possibly also located. I might have seen two or three episodes; I don't think that there were that many more.

Comment: Just as a note the genre tags are ___not___ to be used to classify works of fiction. You might also consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: Did they stay in this other world for several episodes at a time? Through the entire show? Did they go to a new world every time?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that this is the show *[Read All About It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_All_About_It!_(TV_series))*, produced in Canada for American public television.  It features three kids who get into a disused brick house, which does indeed contain a transdimensional teleportation device, built by the uncle of one of the protagonists, who used to own the house.

According to Wikipedia:

> The show is set in the fictitious town of Herbertville, where 11-year-old Chris Anderson inherits his Uncle Derek's coach house seven years after Derek's mysterious disappearance; Derek is now legally presumed dead. The coach house contains two artificially intelligent robots built by Derek: Otto, a device which communicates by printing its thoughts on paper; and Theta, a talking computer with an integrated monitor. The terms of Derek's will stipulate that Chris can only use the coach house before he's 21 if it's for a worthwhile purpose, so he and his friends Lynne and Samantha start a newspaper called The Herbertville Chronicle.
>
> ...
>
> In episode two, the kids discover the coach house also houses a transporter which allows teleportation to and from the galaxy of Trialviron. After inadvertently triggering the transporter, Lynne and Samantha are trapped within Trialviron by Duneedon, the despotic ruler of the galaxy, but manage to escape. This launches a season-long serial, in which the newspaper is focused on unraveling a conspiracy headed by Herbertville mayor Don Eden (the alter ego of Duneedon) who wants to claim King's Park as his own to get a rare mineral he needs to invade Earth.

The pilot (and a number of other episodes) are available on YouTube.